# Create keyboard shortcut in iTerm that performs an action in different pane

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm

I have an iTerm setup where I often have vim running in one split pane, and guard running in a different split pane.

So the keyboard focus stays almost exclusively in the pane running vim.

Once in a while, I would like to have guard run all tasks, which is accomplished by a single enter key press in the guard split pane. But I have to first switch input focus to the different pane, press enter, and switch focus back. So I end up with this keyboard sequence: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (mapped to switch panes), <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

It does work, but it's a lot of key presses.

Can I create a setup, so e.g <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> could trigger en <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress in the 'other' pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever worked with Automator or Applescripts?

You can create a new services with automator executing an Applescript which then "presses" the keys. To that service you can then add a shortcut (⌘+R) under "System Preferences" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Services".

In your case the Applescript would be

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "[" using command down
```

If you got any questions you can ask :D

Comment: After a bit of struggling, I got it to work. There is a slight problem. As I created a keyboard shortcut using the 'command' button, when the script presses 'return' I am still holding down the 'command' key. Adding a 'delay 0.2' seems to remedy this (it took me a while to figure out the reason why the application switched to/from full screen when I was using the keyboard shortcut, but was working correctly when I executed the service from the services menu.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you got it to work :D